# PHP inside HTML inside PHP

Tags: php, html

I can't make the following work. I know it's because of the PHP function inside the string of HTML, but I don't know how to fix it.

```
echo '<aside class="tipContainer">'.'<div>'.'<h1>'.$header.'</h1>'.'<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/pencil_Tip.gif" alt="">'.'</div>'.'<p>'.$content.'</p>'.'</aside>';
```

I receive this error: unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' in ....

Comment: echo '<aside class="tipContainer">'.'<div>'.'<h1>'.$header.'</h1>'.'<img src="'.bloginfo('template_url').'/images/pencil_Tip.gif" alt="">'.'</div>'.'<p>'.$content.'</p>'.'</aside>';

Comment: You don't need to concatenate  html tags with. (e.g: ) '<div>'.'<h1>' could be changed to '<div><h1>'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP is nested too deep. (php nested in php). Try this:

```
echo '<aside class="tipContainer"><div><h1>'.$header.'</h1><img src="'.bloginfo("template_url").'/images/pencil_Tip.gif" alt=""></div><p>'.$content.'</p></aside>';
```

Comment: You can remove the concatenation being done here `'.'<div>'.'`

Comment: Ok, thanks this did return the URL I need but it did not place it inside the img element's src attr. The URL now appears as a string outside the aside element.

Comment: good call @j08691 . It was some rather deeply nested code, and I had to make sure not to use single quotes when they meant to output strings when it was within another string (it's like inception :) ) and I overlooked this.

Comment: @MarkBubel this is because WordPress `getbloginfo` echo's the output. Use `get_bloginfo()` instead.

Comment: Aha... thanks, William! It now works as expected.

Comment: No need to concatenate so much there. I've edited the answer to remove the unnecessary concatenation =)

Answer (score 11):

Try:

```
echo '<aside class="tipContainer"><div><h1>' . $header . '</h1>'.
     '<img src="' . get_bloginfo('template_url') . '/images/pencil_Tip.gif" ' .
     'alt=""></div><p>' . $content . '</p></aside>';
```

Since you are already inside `<?php ?>` tags for your echo statement, you don't need them when you want to call get_bloginfo().  Just call the function as part of the string concatenation.

Comment: thats just ugly. look at Marvos answer.

Comment: I edited it and it's under review :-)

Comment: I'll upvote if you remove the unneeded concatenations.

Comment: @Thomas I voted to approve the edit, 1 more needed.  Also cleaned up my answer. thanks.

Comment: This solved my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
//stop executing PHP, go to plain HTML
 ?>
<aside class="tipContainer">
<div>  
    <h1><?php echo $header?> </h1>
    <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/pencil_Tip.gif" alt="">
</div>
<p>
<?php echo $content ?>
</p>
</aside>

<?php //start php again
```

often makes for cleaner, easier to maintain code to interweave php into html, rather than the other way aroudn

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
echo '<aside class="tipContainer"><div><h1>' . $header . '</h1><img src="'
. bloginfo('template_url')
. '/images/pencil_Tip.gif" alt=""></div><p>' . $content . '</p></aside>';
```

Comment: +1 removed unneeded concatenation

Comment: Okay, cool.  But why did you ADD unnecessary concatenation by pulling $header and $content out of the string?  You don't need to do that for simple variables like that in PHP.

Comment: That doesn't work. Variables inside single quotes are not interpreted

Comment: Yep, you're right.  I must use double quotes instinctively, and my test of this had double quotes.  Learn something new daily.

Comment: Also note that there were much discussions on what is faster, single or double quotes. But today it doesn't really matter. There are operations (database, regular expressions, ...) which need a magnitude more time.

Comment: It's nonetheless something to be aware of -- and I wasn't.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<aside class="tipContainer">'.'<div>'.'<h1>'.$header.'</h1>'.'<img src="' . bloginfo('template_url') . '/images/pencil_Tip.gif" alt="">'.'</div>'.'<p>'.$content.'</p>'.'</aside>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Explanation why it not works:

```
'<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images ...
'______ php string _______'            '__ another php string ...
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
                           this is not part of the sting,
                           because you just closed it.
```

Solutions:

- `'aaa' . "'bbb'" . 'ccc'` : alternate quoting style
- `'aaa\'bbb\'ccc'` : quote the single-quote in the string
- `"aaa'bbb'ccc"`   : use double quotes to quote a string containing single quotes

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<aside class="tipContainer"><div><h1>'.$header.'</h1><img src="' . bloginfo('template_url') . '/images/pencil_Tip.gif" alt=""></div><p>'.$content.'</p></aside>';
```

Answer (score 0):

try the below,

--> Avoid as much concatenation as possible, no need to split/concatenate strings often, ex : "string1" . "string2" is not required, simply do "string1string2" to avoid confusion.

--> Use an IDE, It helps a lot to debug syntax errors.

```
<?php
echo '<aside class="tipContainer"><div><h1>'. $header. '</h1><img src="' . bloginfo('template_url') . '"/images/pencil_Tip.gif" alt=""></div><p>'.$content.'</p></aside>';
?>
```